# How to suppress the disk cannot be written to because it is write protected. Please remove the write protection from the volume in drive in C#

Tags: c#, .net

If my flash drive is write protected, I am facing following issue

Scenario:
`Directory.Create()` gives the message as mentioned below before throwing `IOException`.
But I want to avoid this pop message and handle it in `IOException` catch block

The pop up says:
The disk cannot be written to because it is write protected. Please remove the write protection from the volume in drive.

How to suppress this pop up message and handle it in `IOException` catch block ?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `Exception` class with relevant message or implement your own Exception class such as `MyException()`

```
try{
    Directory.Create(...);
}catch (IOException ex){
    throw new Exception("Directory cannot be created.", ex);
}


[Serializable]
public class MyException: Exception
{
    public MyException()
    {
    }

    public MyException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public MyException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `try new Exception("Your disk protected");`? If you are rethrowing then you are breaking at least 2 cardinal rules of Exception handling. Always wrap and throw (gives more information). Always make your Exception `Serializable`.

Comment: Still missing the wrapping of the original exception. How do you know that its a flash drive? I see no code to confirm that the hardware is a flash drive, could be a Mag Core, could be an experimental storage drive like millipede...

Comment: You don't even know its a permission issue. It could be disk full. The disk could be readonly (CD/DVD/BD-R).

Comment: @Aron I just pointed OP's issue, and you could give your anwser as you have better then mine. 194 downvote vs 230 upvote, interesting statistics on your profile

Comment: I think the OP is very confused. I believe the OP thinks the VS debug break on exception behavior is part of his program. I think your answer is not answering his question, be it a question coming from his misunderstanding.

Comment: @Aron There are even  more interesting then yours : http://stackoverflow.com/users/2491900/shree-pat18

Comment: @Aron oh my god http://stackoverflow.com/users/16076/mitch-wheat it is full down of downvoters